# I want to execute an if else statement inside for each loop only once in PHP

Tags: php

My code is:

```
<tbody>
                <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblcourse`";
            $mydb->setQuery($query);
            $cur = $mydb->loadResultList();
            foreach ($cur as $result)
            {?>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" width="20%">
                    <?php
                    foreach($arr as $v)
                    {
                        if ($result->COURSEID==$v) {
                            echo "<a href='index.php?q=rollout'> Roll out</a>";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<a href='index.php?q=enroll'> Enroll</a>";
                        }
    
                }?>

                 </td>
            </tr>
              <?php
            }
          ?>
        </tbody>
```

If $arr has 2 elements ($cur has 5 elements) then
**i want output like this** :-

- rollout
- enroll
- enroll
- rollout
- enroll

instead I'm getting :-

- rollout enroll
- enroll enroll
- enroll enroll
- enroll rollout
- enroll enroll

Comment: Please, use `var_dump()`, I think it's passing in `if()` condition and getting something that's on `else` statement, because it's like "not breaking line" if you see the outputs.

Comment: I think it's slightly difficult to provide a good answer to this question without seeing at least a *sample* of how `$arr` *could* be defined.

Comment: Your loops are nested. If `$arr` has 2 elements and `$cur` has 5, that's you see 10 outputs; 2 * 5 is 10.

Comment: Since your `$arr` has 2 elements. And you have `foreach` loop against `$arr` you have always 2 `echo` per `$result`. What do you need instead - is not clear.

Comment: I think you need to use `break` and maybe a flag variable to check if the condition is satisfied or not even when the inner loop iteration is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you want to output ROLL OUT if the COURSEID of $result is one of the values in arr and otherwise you want to output ENROLL.

Remove the `foreach($arr as $v)` loop and replace with

```
if (in_array($result->COURSEID,$arr)) {
  echo "<a href='index.php?q=rollout'> Roll out</a>";
} else {
  echo "<a href='index.php?q=enroll'> Enroll</a>";
}
```

Comment: It works, although a minor error.....u  forgot a closing parenthesis in first line. Thankyou